# Use a macro instead of a loop for faster execution in GAMS?

Tags: loops, gams-math

Consider the following code:

```
set t               / 1 * 300000 /;
parameter pop(t)    / 1 3456 /
          growth(t) ;

growth(t) = 25;

loop(t,

   pop(t+1) = pop(t) + growth(t);
   
);
```

This takes pretty much time for GAMS to run.
Instead of using loop, is it possible to use macro instead to make the execution faster?

I have tried with:

```
$macro mymacro(t)  \
& pop(&t+1) = pop(&t) + growth(&t);

mymacro(t);
```

The problem is that, it does not use the loop.
I have also tried with:

```
mymacro("1");
mymacro("2");
...
mymacro("300000");
```

But it gives an error.

Comment: Is this the real data, i.e., is the growth constant for each t? Or is that just dummy data and in the real model, the growth varies?

Comment: It is dummy data. In the real model, the growth varies.

Comment: I think a macro will not help here. But you can at least make the look faster (not super fast), by adjusting your index operations to look back instead of front and do this instead of your loop: `loop(t$(ord(t)>1), pop(t) = pop(t-1) + growth(t-1); )`